# Change major mode for buffer without a corresponding file

Tags: init-file, buffers, major-mode

I want to change the major mode from `fundamental-mode` to `compilation-mode` for a buffer which contains some generated output named for eg. `*results*`. I've tried to add an entry to `auto-mode-alist` but if i understand correctly this works only with buffers which have a corresponding filename.

I've tried to add it in the list like this but this is not working.

```
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\*result\\*" . compilation-mode))
```

> UPDATE:

After some digging in I found that this particular lisp snippet is filling the buffer with data.

```
(start-process "result" "*result*" "some_unix_command")
```

> UPDATE:

This buffer is generated from a 3rd party plugin so i'd rather not start and change the src lisp code. I'd like to handle this on a different level.

I've already checked if I can attach a hook somewhere where the buffer is created and the answer is negative.

Anyone with some ideas on how I can do this?

Comment: Can you find the function that creates that buffer? Maybe it runs a hook or you can advise the function?

Comment: How about?:  `M-x compilation-mode`

Comment: @lawlist I want to change it automatically

Comment: @DanRobertson good idea, will try this in a bit

Comment: Such buffers don't just magically get "generated output": some code must be creating them and putting output into it.  What is this code you're using for that?

Comment: Please provide details, e.g., a step-by-step recipe to reproduce the problem, starting from `emacs -Q` (no init file). Say what you see at each step and what you expected to see.

Comment: @Drew I'm not saying that there is a bug in emacs, the doc says clearly that what i'm trying to do won't work. 
`The auto-mode-alist variable is an AssociationList that associates MajorModes with a pattern to match a buffer filename when it is first opened`

Comment: My comment is saying that the question is unclear (to me), not that what you described is an Emacs bug.

Comment: Can you state which 3rd party custom plugin you are using? We could have a look there. We would no longer need to blindly guess.

Comment: @Tobias i'm using `cmake-ide` and the buffer which captures some output is `*cmake*`

Comment: @mihai: then your question should mention `cmake-ide`.  Also please tell us which *command* (or Elisp chunk in your .emacs) you're using that ends up creating this buffer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general answer to problems of this kind [is given by user Lawlist](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/55286/2370). I consider in the following your special situation.

You stated in [a comment](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/55281/change-major-mode-for-buffer-without-a-corresponding-file?noredirect=1#comment86498_55281) that you want to use `compilation-mode` for [`cmake-ide`](https://github.com/atilaneves/cmake-ide/blob/master/cmake-ide.el).

The following code advises that package for that purpose probably with minimal impact on the package:

```el
(defcustom my-cide-callback-functions
  '(my-cide-compilation-mode-activate)
  "Special hook for cide.
Each function registered here is run like a process sentinel
for the cmake process after cmake has finished."
  :type 'hook
  :group 'cmake-ide)

(defun my-cide-compilation-mode-activate (process _event)
  "Activate `compilation-mode' in PROCESS buffer after compilation.
This function can be used in `my-cide-callback-functions'."
  (let ((buf (process-buffer process)))
    (when (and (null (process-live-p process))
               (buffer-live-p buf))
      (with-current-buffer buf
        (compilation-mode)))))

(defun my-cide--register-a-callback (callback)
  "Register CALLBACK to be called when CMake finishes running."
  (set-process-sentinel
   (get-process "cmake")
   `(lambda (process event)
     (funcall ,callback process event)
     (run-hook-with-args 'my-cide-callback-functions process event))))

(advice-add 'cide--register-a-callback :override #'my-cide--register-a-callback)
```

Disclaimer: I do not have `cmake-ide` and do not want to install it if it is not necessary for debugging.
Please test the code and report back whether it works or not.

Comment: I'm getting the following error @Tobias
 
```Debugger entered--Lisp error: (void-variable callback)
  (funcall callback process event)
  (lambda (process event) (funcall callback process event) (run-hook-with-args (quote my-cide-callback-functions) process event))(#<process cmake> "finished\n")
```

Comment: @mihai Very interesting. I thought it should work because `cmake-ide.el` uses lexical binding. I've changed the approach a bit. Could you try again? (Back-quoting + substituting by comma-operator)

Comment: Works exactly as i expected.

Comment: @Tobias You won't get a lexical closure unless the file that *your* code is in uses `lexical-binding`.  I presume that wasn't the case.

Comment: @phils Looking [at the code](https://github.com/atilaneves/cmake-ide/blob/master/cmake-ide.el) there is `-*- lexical-binding: t; -*-` in the first comment line. Otherwise I would not have written that this *is interesting*. Maybe the OP uses an older version of `cmake-ide`. `set-process-sentinel` should work with lexical binding, shouldn't it? Do you have opposite experiences?

Comment: @Tobias: As @phils said, whether lexical-binding is in use in the cmake-ide.el file is irrelevant, what matters is whether it's in use in the file where `my-cide--register-a-callback` is defined.

Comment: @Stefan Yes you are right of course. My bad. Thanks for the clarification. Maybe, the OP has put the code into the init file and his init file has no lexical binding. The only argument against lexical binding in the init file would be legacy code, am I right? So maybe the OP could transit to lexical binding.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of running `start-process` and then calling `compilation-mode` on the output:

```lisp
(start-process "result" "*result*" "some_unix_command")
```

... another option is to use the `compile` command, which automatically generates the output buffer in `compilation-mode`:

```lisp
(compile "some_unix_command")
```

Alternatively, consider invoking `compilation-mode` *after* the process finishes running when using `start-process` by using a process-sentinel:

https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Sentinels.html

This following linked thread contains a few examples of using a process sentinel:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24548536/penetrating-the-set-process-sentinel-hierarchy-with-let-bound-variables

Comment: The actual question here is whether he has control of the code or not and how the environment of his lines looks like. IMHO your answer is a bit too early.

Comment: @Tobias -- In the event the O.P. chooses to modify his/her question to elaborate by providing the forum participants with details about a specific library being used by the O.P. that utilizes the example in the question; i.e., `(start-process "result" "*result*" "some_unix_command")`, then a more precise solution can be suggested.  Inasmuch as the question is general in nature, only a general answer is appropriate at this time.

Comment: IMHO we are not yet at a point where we can decide whether your solution is applicable.

Comment: Well, only @mihai will be deciding whether this solution is applicable; but regardless this answer may well prove beneficial to other people looking at the Q&A, so I think it's a useful answer to include, even if the question currently remains somewhat unclear.

Comment: I've indicated in my answer that you described the general approach (+1).